# Error trying to start robot remotely with smartcard from UiPath Orchestrator

Tags: authentication, certificate, smartcard, uipath-orchestrator

The UiPath Orchestrator and robot are set up according to the instructions in the UiPath Guide. When we now try to run a process remotely on a machine with a Developer License the following Error shows up in the Orchestrator logs:

> Could not start executor. The requested certificate could not be received. (Exception HRESULT: 0x8010002D)

and the following shows in the Windows Eventviewer:

> StartProcessInSession:session.cpp@255: Unable to validate credentials: error: 2148532269

The errorcodes map to SCARD_E_CERTIFICATE_UNAVAILABLE according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/authentication-return-values but I could not find any information on to why this error is occuring.

The manual login is working as usual and we tried it on multiple machines with the same result. Machines without smartcards are working fine.

Does anybody know what the root of this error could be?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue concerning the different types of license. To my knowledge just having a "developer" (I assume here you mean a license to use Studio) does not mean that automations can be launched on that machine from Orchestrator. Orchestrator requires that an unattended bot license be present, which is distinct from a license for Studio or an Attended Bot.

I would recommend closely reading the documentation (https://robot.uipath.com/docs/about-licensing) on licensing to make sure that the you are only trying to call an unattended bot from Orchestrator.

Comment: No this is not the case. The execution of bots from the orchestrator is possible on developer machines.